# EF 4.3.1 code first table index mapping or creation

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, code-first, table-index

I've been searchin around a lot for a way to create, or configure a specific index on a table from EF code first, but really can't find a thing. mapping fluent Api doesn't seem to expose any means to do this. What am I missing?

Comment: You're not missing anything. Code first is missing that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262590/entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api-adding-indexes-to-columns

Comment: Thank you. I was almost sure it wasn't possible with fluent api or dataannotations, but confirmation is always nice. I'll try some workarounds and if I find something interesting, I'l post it here. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can add index creation either to custom database intitializer as mentioned in linked answer or you can use [code based migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx). Migrations provide [support for index creation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829515%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, but ir feels wrong having to add a migration for something that is not really a change in your database but part of the initial definition. Creating a Index, or constraint should be part of the mapping process as well as the migration process. As a workaround is a nice one though.

Comment: You can scaffold your initial model definition as initial code based migration and add index creation. Anyway there is currently no better way.

Comment: The reason it feels wrong is that you understand databases. I would allege that code first is for people who don't.

Comment: If you don't understand database you most probably don't know about indices. I think there are some indices created automatically when using migrations.

Comment: With mapping, indexes are indeed created, somo of them redundant even. I wouldn't say code first is for people who don't understand DB, I like it, and I love the fact that it can be used out of the box for some simple yet usual scenarios. I miss some advanced config features for some advanced scenarios. This one posted here is one of them, and also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799328/entityframework-4-3-1-code-first-navigation-property-mapping-and-visibility).